# Running ASP.NET application shows error 500 but .NET CORE runs well

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, internal-server-error

All ASP.NET projects fails to run on my system, it throws `HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error`. But all my .NET CORE projects runs fine.
What could be the issue?
Kindly find screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Are you running the codes from visual studio or IIS? If VS then try to open the VS with "Run as Administrator" option.

Comment: @rahatur I am running it on VS and have tried to run the application as adiministrator but still showing the same above error

Comment: Try to close the web servers from the task bar then clear the dotnet cache by deleting everything in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder depending on the version of framework you are using for the asp.net project.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have mixed applications in your App Pool.

Try creating a new application pool for the app - and ensure it is set to the correct settings. You may have a .Net2 and .Net4 application with same legacy app pool.

If that doesn't work - post your app pool settings

Comment: @Brainiac005 Ok, well maybe post your configuration so we're not just guessing

Comment: Name: DefaultAppPool. .NET CLR Version: v4.0.30319, Managed Pipeline mode: Integrated.

Comment: Note: My project is not deployed to IIS, I am only trying to run my code from my visual studio of which the error 500.0 kept on showing